# Get the Mean of Time - ABAP

Tags: datetime, abap

Is there a way in ABAP to get the mean of a time set?

eg: An event occurred at the following times

- 08:30
- 08:45
- 09:00

If you take the mean time the event occurred from the above data set, it;s 08:45. Is there a way to calculate this in ABAP?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://scn.sap.com/message/16921270

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the same question was posted and has received answers on http://scn.sap.com/message/16921270

Comment: SCN is a private forum. If the question has not been previously answered on here, I would say it is of value to have it recorded here (I am an ABAP developer with SCN access, and I cannot view the link you posted, it comes up as restricted).

Comment: @TimRadcliffe same thoughts exactly, but as of now the question has been voted out of public access. I got the above to work, will post the answer here as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods I used was to convert the time to Unix format. This mean that I could get the average by normal division.

Following is the FM used to convert to Unix time;

```
    CALL METHOD CL_PCO_UTILITY=>CONVERT_ABAP_TIMESTAMP_TO_JAVA(
      EXPORTING
        IV_DATE      = LD_IV_DATE
        "IV_MSEC      = LD_IV_MSEC
        IV_TIME      = LD_IV_TIME
      IMPORTING
        EV_TIMESTAMP = IN_UNIX_2 ).
```

Input: Date and Time
Output: DateTime in Unix format

Then just add the average to 19700101 date.

Can be done with the following FM;

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD' "
    EXPORTING
      TIMESTAMP_IN  = 19700101000000            " timestamp     UTC Time Stamp in Short Form (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)
      TIMEZONE      = 'UTC'                     " timezone      Time Zone
      UNIT          = 'S'                       " t006-msehi    Unit of measurement
      DURATION      = IN_RUN_AVG
    IMPORTING
      TIMESTAMP_OUT = IN_AVG_FINAL              " timestamp     UTC Time Stamp in Short Form (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)
    .  "  TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD
```

This method can be used since the Unix time is time count in seconds from 1970/01/01

Answer (score 0):

do this:

data: lv_clock type sy-uzeit,
lv_type type sy-uzeit.

Get time.
lv_time = sy-uzeit.

your code...

get time.
lv_clock = sy-uzeit.

lv_clock = lv_clock - lv_time.

write: / lv_clock.

Or, you can use the function 'TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD'